# Angular5 Karma test with moment

Tags: angular, karma-runner, momentjs

In my angular app, I am trying to unit test some stuff using momentjs.

When running my test, I keep getting         `TypeError: moment(...).locale(...).format is not a function`
I did try `https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-moment`

but unfortunately it made no difference.

Any idea how can I use `moment` in my `karma` unit tests.

```
karma.conf.js:

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli', 'moment-2.9.0'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-moment'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client:{
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 50000,
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

I have a `pipe` using `momentjs` :

```
import * as moment from "moment";

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateText'
})
export class DateTextPipe implements PipeTransform {

 ...
 transform(value) {
   return moment(value).format('LL')
 }
}
```

Comment: did you import the relevant packages add your karma code.

Comment: Moment should be loaded in tests the same way it's loaded in production. There are not enough details. How is moment being used in the app? With `import`?

Comment: I added the karma.conf.js